# Finding a Closed Form to a Squared Relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

I have: $a_n = (a_{n-1})^2$ with $a_1 = 4$. We can do $4 = (a_{1-1})^2 \iff 4 = a_0^2 \iff 2 = a_0$

My attempt: I wanted to work with a "top down" approach.

$$(1) \qquad a_n = (a_{n-1})^2 \\ (2) \qquad a_{n-1} = (a_{n-2})^2\cdot(a_{n-1})^2  \\ (3)\qquad a_{n-2} = (a_{n-3})^2 \cdot (a_{n-2})^2\cdot(a_{n-1})^2 \\ \text{See that we know $a_{n-1}$ so we can expand this out} \\ a_{n-2} = (a_{n-3})^2 \cdot (a_{n-2})^2 \cdot (a_{n-2})^2\cdot(a_{n-1})^2 \\ \vdots \\ a_k = (a_{n-k})^{2^k} \\ \text{Let $k = n$} \\ a_{n} = (a_{n-n})^{2^{n}} \\ a_{n} = (a_0)^{2^{n}} \\ a_{n} = 2^{2^n}$$

I don't know how to go about finding the first $a_{n-1}$ term. I don't know if multiplying by the square is the right approach like what I am doing on line $(2)$. Is this the right way to finding the recurrence of a squared variable?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a_1=2^{2^1}, a_2=2^4=2^{2^2},   a_3=2^8=2^{2^3},...,  a_n=2^{2^n}$

$a_2=a_1^2$

$a_3=a_2^2$

$a_4=a_3^2$

.
.
.

$a_n=a_{n-1}^2$

$a_n=a_1\times a_1\times a_2 \times a_3\times a_4\times ... \times a_{n-1}=2^2(=2^{2^1})\times 2^2(=2^{2^1})\times 2^4(=2^{2^2})\times 2^8(=2^{2^3})\times 2^{16}(=2^{2^4}) \times ... \times 2^{2^{n-1}} =2^{2^1+2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4+...+2^{n-1}}=2^{2^1+\frac{1-2^n}{1-2}-1}=2^{2^n} $

Comment: Thank you! But where does the two come from in something of like my situation?

Comment: I have added more steps.

Comment: Again, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome,